# ¿Como mostrar los registros que voy cargando en la base de datos en el table html?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Este es el codigo en php y html que tengo funciona bien,guarda los registros que le cargo,pero lo que no hace es mostrar la fila que acabo de cargar en la pagina luego de que hago click en el boton "cargar" tengo que recargar la pagina y me pone la advertencia de los campos vacios.
Yo quiero que luego de hacer click me muestre la fila que acabo de ingresar.

```
     <?php
     include("conexion.php");

     $enlace=conectarse();
     $query2="SELECT * FROM netbook_alumno" ;//consulta para mostrar la db
     $resultado = $enlace->query($query2);
     mysqli_close($enlace);

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    if(isset($_POST["cargar"])){
       $error=array();
    if(empty($_POST['campo1'])){
       $error[]='Por favor no dejes el campo de numero de CUIL en blanco';
   }else{
       $campo1=$_POST['campo1'];
   }
   if(empty($_POST['campo2'])){
      $error[]="No deje el campo de nombre en blanco";
   }else{
      $campo2=$_POST['campo2'];
   }
  if(empty($_POST['campo3'])){
      $error[]="No deje el campo de ID-NetBook en blanco";
  }else{
     $campo3=$_POST['campo3']; 
  }
     $campo4=$_POST['campo4'];

    if(empty($error)){
       $conexion=conectarse();
     //pregunta si hay registros,si no hay hace el insert
      $consultando_query="SELECT * FROM netbook_alumno WHERE cuil = 
      '$campo1'";
      $respuesta_query = $conexion->query($consultando_query);
      $contar=mysqli_num_rows($respuesta_query);
    //hace el insert
    if($contar==0){
        $conexion2=conectarse();
        $insertar_datos="INSERT INTO netbook_alumno 
     (cuil,nombre,id_netbook_alumno,observaciones)VALUES
        ('$campo1','$campo2','$campo3','$campo4')";
        $consulta_query2=$conexion2->query($insertar_datos);
        echo"
        <script>alert('Datos Guardados');</script>";
          }else{
         /*ventana pop up*/
         print '<script>'; 
         print 'alert("Esa netbook ya existe.");'; 
         print '</script>';  
          }
      }else{
        foreach($error as  $values){
        echo '<li>'.$values.'</li>';

         }
      }
   }
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Asignar NetBook a Alumno</title>
</head>
<body >

<h1>Cambios&nbsp; Stock&nbsp; Netbooks</h1>
 <form action="asignarAAlumno.php" name="mi_formulario" method="post">
 <p>
  <label for="textfield">CUIL:</label>
  <input type="text" name="campo1" id="campo1"  value= "<?php echo  $c1 ?>">
</p> 
<p>
 <label for="texfield">Nombre:</label>
 <input type="text" name="campo2" id="campo2" value = "<?php echo $c2 ?>">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="textfield">ID-NetBook:</label>
  <input type="text" name="campo3" id="campo3" value ="<?php echo $c3 ?>">
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="textfield">Observaciones</label>
  <input type="text" name="campo4" id="campo4" value="<?php echo $c4 ?>">
 </p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="cargar" id="button" value="Cargar">
</p>
</form>
<br>

<table border="3" >
    <tr  id="encabezado">
        <td>Cuil</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ID-NetBook</td>
        <td>Observaciones</td>

    </tr>

    <?php 

   while($campo=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){

     ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $campo[0] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $campo[1] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $campo[2] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $campo[3] ?></td>
    </tr>
   <?php 
     }
   ?>
      </table>
    </br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es hacer tu consulta despues de ingresar el nuevo dato.  Ademas, no necesitas crear una conexion cada vez que haces una consulta.  Algo asi:

```
<?php
     include("conexion.php");         

    if(isset($_POST["cargar"])){
       $error=array();
    if(empty($_POST['campo1'])){
       $error[]='Por favor no dejes el campo de numero de CUIL en blanco';
   }else{
       $campo1=$_POST['campo1'];
   }
   if(empty($_POST['campo2'])){
      $error[]="No deje el campo de nombre en blanco";
   }else{
      $campo2=$_POST['campo2'];
   }
  if(empty($_POST['campo3'])){
      $error[]="No deje el campo de ID-NetBook en blanco";
  }else{
     $campo3=$_POST['campo3']; 
  }
     $campo4=$_POST['campo4'];
    $conexion=conectarse();
    if(empty($error)){

     //pregunta si hay registros,si no hay hace el insert
      $consultando_query="SELECT * FROM netbook_alumno WHERE cuil = 
      '$campo1'";
      $respuesta_query = $conexion->query($consultando_query);
      $contar=mysqli_num_rows($respuesta_query);
    //hace el insert
      if($contar==0){            
        $insertar_datos="INSERT INTO netbook_alumno 
     (cuil,nombre,id_netbook_alumno,observaciones)VALUES
        ('$campo1','$campo2','$campo3','$campo4')";
        $consulta_query2=$conexion->query($insertar_datos);
        echo"
        <script>alert('Datos Guardados');</script>";
          }else{
         /*ventana pop up*/
         print '<script>'; 
         print 'alert("Esa netbook ya existe.");'; 
         print '</script>';  
          }
      }else{
        foreach($error as  $values){
        echo '<li>'.$values.'</li>';

         }
      }
   }
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Asignar NetBook a Alumno</title>
</head>
<body >

<h1>Cambios&nbsp; Stock&nbsp; Netbooks</h1>
 <form action="asignarAAlumno.php" name="mi_formulario" method="post">
 <p>
  <label for="textfield">CUIL:</label>
  <input type="text" name="campo1" id="campo1"  value= "<?php echo  $c1 ?>">
</p> 
<p>
 <label for="texfield">Nombre:</label>
 <input type="text" name="campo2" id="campo2" value = "<?php echo $c2 ?>">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="textfield">ID-NetBook:</label>
  <input type="text" name="campo3" id="campo3" value ="<?php echo $c3 ?>">
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="textfield">Observaciones</label>
  <input type="text" name="campo4" id="campo4" value="<?php echo $c4 ?>">
 </p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="cargar" id="button" value="Cargar">
</p>
</form>
<br>

<table border="3" >
    <tr  id="encabezado">
        <td>Cuil</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ID-NetBook</td>
        <td>Observaciones</td>

    </tr>

    <?php 

     $query2="SELECT * FROM netbook_alumno" ;//consulta para mostrar la db
     $resultado = $conexion->query($query2);
     mysqli_close($conexion);

     while($campo=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){

     ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $campo[0] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $campo[1] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $campo[2] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $campo[3] ?></td>
    </tr>
   <?php 
     }
   ?>
      </table>
    </br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias,me funciono y elimine lo de las conexiones innecesarias.

Comment: De nada @Masterweed